# I need to combine all elements in a list using only prelude and no other modules in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

n is the first argument, and a list is the second. The elements can be can selected several times and in different order.
So it will look something like:

```
com 1 [1,2,3] = [ [1], [2], [3] ]

com 2 [1,2,3] = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

Ive written these and they work but i need a general function

```
com :: Int -> [t] -> [[t]]
com x [] = []
com 1 ys = [[z]| z <- ys]
com 2 ys = [z:q:[] | z <- ys, q <- ys]
```

I think it will look something like this:

```
com x ys
  | x < 0 = []
  | otherwise qs = [ z:[] | z <- ys ] com (x-1) qs
```

all help appreciated

Comment: Looks almost exactly like what [this question wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951089/get-permutations-of-length-n-of-a-list-in-haskell).

Comment: And `qs = [ z:[] | z <- ys ] com (x-1) qs` does not make any sense at all, since a list does not take any arguments...

Comment: Yes thats obvious to me now, oops. What im trying to do with this code is to repeat the add list element x-times

Comment: What do you mean with *i needed it as a parameterd*?

Comment: I prematurely sent the message haha.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer btw, but do you have any ideas for a solution. What i find hard is making the code repeat.

Comment: Your function is the same as [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) where `Applicative m` is specialized to `[]`. The source code for that function is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM).

Comment: The case when `x = 0` should be `[[]]`, there's 1 list of length 0, the empty list `[]`.

Comment: You could also implement it as `com x ys = sequence (replicate x ys)`

Answer (score 4):

You started good:
`com :: Int -> [t] -> [[t]]
com x [] = {- [] -} [[]]     -- thanks to @cirdec for spotting this
com 1 ys = [ [z]   | z <- ys]
com 2 ys = [ [z,q] | z <- ys, q <- ys]                                 -- <<----`

now continue with it for a while:
`com 3 ys = [ [y,z,q] | y <- ys, z <- ys, q <- ys]
         = [ y:[z,q] | y <- ys, z <- ys, q <- ys]
         = [ y:[z,q] | y <- ys, [z,q] <- [ [z,q] | z <- ys, q <- ys]]  -- <<----
         = [ y:r2    | y <- ys, r2    <- [ [z,q] | z <- ys, q <- ys]]  -- <<----
         = [ y:r2    | y <- ys, r2    <- ...... ]`

right? We can always replace equals by equals, in Haskell!

```
com 4 ys = [ [x,y,z,q] | x <- ys, y <- ys, z <- ys, q <- ys]
         = [ x:[y,z,q] | x <- ys, y <- ys, z <- ys, q <- ys]
         = ....
         = [ x:r3      | x <- ys, r3 <- ...... ]
```

can you continue this? can you finish up this line of thought?

```
com n ys | n > 4 = [ x:r | x <- ys, r <- .... (n-1) .... ]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157604/discussion-on-answer-by-will-ness-i-need-to-combine-all-elements-in-a-list-using).